# 15 Hex in Binary form, explanation required?

Tags: math, binary, hex

I really really really can't understand how 15hex converted in Binary form gives me 10101bin.

That should be easy but I can't get it

Comment: That's not a programming related question but basic math. Read about number systems.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - be nice. We all start out at ground zero at some point in our journey.

Comment: @selbie But in fact that's not a programming question, and neither related to any of the tagged languages.

Comment: This question belongs on a math forum.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about number base / radix /  [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
0x15 == 1*16 + 5*1 == 21

21 == 1*16 + 0*8 + 1*4 + + 0*2 + 1*1 == 10101 (binary)
```

What's not to love?

Answer (score 1):

Well it's simple. In decimal base, number 15 means

10 + 5, because the number 1 means 1 * 10, and number 5 means 5 * 1.

And in hex, number 15 means:

`1` * 16 + `5` * 1, meaning its 21. 21 in binary is 10101.

Comment: Love you. Love YOU.

Comment: I love you too, random citizen!

Answer (score 0):

**How to convert hex to binary**

Convert each hex digit to 4 binary digits according to this table:

```
 Hex Binary
0   0000
1   0001
2   0010
3   0011
4   0100
5   0101
6   0110
7   0111
8   1000
9   1001
A   1010
B   1011
C   1100
D   1101
E   1110
F   1111
```

Example #1

```
Convert (4E)16 to binary:

(4)16 = (0100)2
(E)16 = (1110)2
```

So

```
(4E)16 = (01001110)2
```

**Example #2**

Convert(4A01)16 to binary:

```
(4)16 = (0100)2
(A)16 = (1010)2
(0)16 = (0000)2
(1)16 = (0001)2
```

So

```
(4A01)16 = (0100101000000001)2
```